# Having and group by confusion Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Disclaimer: This is a purely theoretical question since I do have a correct working code.

Hello,

I have a simple question with what I guess will not be a simple answer.
What I am trying to achieve with this code is to obtain all sender IDs and the message IDs of all the messages which were sent by a sender from whom we have received at least two messages.

This is the correct and working code:

```
select msg_id, sender_id
from messages
where sender_id in(
select sender_id
from messages
group by sender_id
having count(sender_id)>1);
```

My question is why the following code will not do. It returns an empty table with no data.
And what I mean is what are the inner workings of group by and having which prevent the following code from working. You can get to the level of relational calculus if need be.

```
select sender_id, msg_id from messages
group by sender_id, msg_id
having count(sender_id) > 1;
```

One last thing to consider is that this obviously works:

```
select sender_id from messages
group by sender_id
having count(sender_id) > 1;
```

Then why does adding one more column breaks the results?

Comment: _"You can get to the level of relational calculus"_ - `GROUP BY` is one particular _reduction_ operator as far relational calculus is concerned - but that's kinda moot as SQL is a joke of a travesty of an implementation of Codd's relational calculus.

Comment: Assuming msg_id is unique for every row, it means grouping with msg_id just results in every row in their own group, ie, their sender_id count is always 1

Comment: @Martheen this sounds reasonable assuming SQL cares about msg_id whilst being specifically told to count sender_id.

Comment: It's only being told to count sender_id, yes - but it's being told (via the group-by clause) to count it *for every combination* of msg_id and sender_id.

Comment: @Dai yeah, we had a profesor who translated Codd's rules to our mother tongue and was an expert in this field and he abided them blindly. His SQL queries were useless intelectual garbage which would seldom see any practical use in a production environment. I like theoretical backgrounds to stuff regarding coding as it helps oft but holding onto them too much results in overally complicating stuff and being generally .. too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution (that does not involve self-join) is to use the analytic `COUNT` function and an inline-view:

```sql
SELECT msg_id, sender_id
FROM   (
  SELECT msg_id, sender_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sender_id) AS num_senders
  FROM   messages
)
WHERE  num_senders > 1;
```

---

> My question is why the following code will not do. [...]
>
> ```sql
> select sender_id, msg_id from messages
> group by sender_id, msg_id
> having count(sender_id) > 1;
> ```

You `GROUP BY` both `sender_id` and `msg_id` so if each group has only a single row (i.e. because either `msg_id` is unique or each `msg_id` and `sender_id` tuple is unique) then the `HAVING` filter will never be met and so all the rows are excluded from the output.

> One last thing to consider is that this obviously works:
>
> ```sql
> select sender_id from messages
> group by sender_id
> having count(sender_id) > 1;
> ```

Yes, because you are not grouping by both `sender_id` and `msg_id`; you are only grouping by `sender_id` and there will be multiple `msg_id` within that group.

Comment: Thank you! I did not need any other solutions but the answer did help get my thoughts together.